# TFS 2015 Update 2 on premise - Daylight saving issue

Tags: rest, tfs, timezone, tfs-2015

We are using TFS 2015 via the REST api to find out what changesets where checked in between two datetimes:

```
http://internal01:8080/tfs/AppCollection/hr/_apis/tfvc/changesets?fromDate=2016-10-25T14:40:01.570&itemPath=$/HR/P1/Tempest/DevQA&api-version=1.0&toDate=2016-10-25T14:50:01.570
```

The issue is that in the UK we finished daylight saving last week.

Even though a changeset in visual studio shows the correct time of checkin

The rest API is returning this items time as an hour behind (the checkin was last week during daylight saving.

```
"createdDate":"2016-10-25T13:49:44.573Z",
```

It's returning the change set, which is great, but the returned value is not accounting for daylight saving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is returning the date in in "Zulu Time", or [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), as per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) specification for Date Times

You can tell be the trailing "Z" on the string:

```
"createdDate":"2016-10-25T13:49:44.573Z",
                                      ^
```

This is quite a common thing for API's to do, remember the exact same API's are in Visual Studio Team Services, which is hosted across many time zones and accessed by clients in multiple timezones.

In these cases it is the job of the client to convert the time into local time.

A trivial C#/.NET implementation is:

```
var createdDateUtc = "2016-10-25T13:49:44.573Z";
var createdDateLocal = DateTimeOffset.Parse(createdDateUtc).ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine(createdDateLocal);

//Prints: 25/10/2016 14:49:44 +01:00
```

Comment: THANK YOU! that's been bugging us for a while.
Would mark it as an answer but my points are not high enough.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I don't think accepting requires any rep (it actually give's rep IIRC).